# Can't find inerface-file declaration for variable

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I'm trying to shift execution of some code to compile time with GHC 8 and
`template-haskel-2.11`. The code looks like this:

```
myThHelper :: FilePath -> Q Exp
myThHelper path =
  runIO (compileThatFile path) >>= liftData
```

This is a simplified version of that code but it hopefully conveys what I'm
trying to do.

Note the
[`liftData`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:liftData)
function, it's new in `template-haskell-2.11` and it promises to “lift” into
expression any instance of `Data`. Very cool and it compiles.

However, when I use it like so:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let compiled = $(myThHelper "/path/to/my/file/foo.txt")
  …
```

I'm getting the following error message from the compiler:

```
• Can't find interface-file declaration for variable Data.Text.Internal.pack
    Probable cause: bug in .hi-boot file, or inconsistent .hi file
    Use -ddump-if-trace to get an idea of which file caused the error
• In the first argument of ‘PName’, namely
    ‘Data.Text.Internal.pack ((:) 'f' ((:) 'o' ((:) 'o' [])))’
  In the first argument of ‘Template’, namely
    ‘PName (Data.Text.Internal.pack ((:) 'f' ((:) 'o' ((:) 'o' []))))’
  In the expression:
```

etc. Any idea what's going on and how to fix it?

---

I confirmed via experiments that the problem only manifests itself when data type to lift has `Text` in it. I'm going to open an issue.

---

[And here it is](https://github.com/bos/text/issues/156).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This seems to be because [`dataToQa`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/src/Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax.html#dataToQa) expects the function that [`toConstr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Data.html#v:toConstr) shows (which is `"pack"` for [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#t:Text)) to be in the same module the data type is defined. So [`liftData`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:liftData) is looking for [`pack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:pack) in [`Data.Text.Internal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text-Internal.html) but [`pack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html#v:pack) is actually in [`Data.Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html).

An easy way to fix it is to just write your own lift function for `Text`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import qualified Data.Text as T
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax

liftText :: T.Text -> Q Exp
liftText txt = AppE (VarE 'T.pack) <$> lift (T.unpack txt)

myThHelper :: FilePath -> Q Exp
myThHelper path =
  runIO (compileThatFile path) >>= liftText
```

---

If text is deep in the structure you want to use, you can use [`dataToExpQ`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:dataToExpQ) which lets you override the lift function for type-specific cases:

```
import Data.Data

liftDataWithText :: Data a => a -> Q Exp
liftDataWithText = dataToExpQ (\a -> liftText <$> cast a)
```

Comment: I fear that "easy way" won't work for me, because my data has `Text` not on top-level, but deep inside.

Comment: @Mark In that case you can use [`dataToExQ`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.11.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:dataToExpQ). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now that is interesting. I'll check it once I have time and accept your answer if it works.

Comment: why casting to Text would work for any Data? cast succeeds when conversion happens between newtype wrappers of the same type. Why would `data Foo ~ Data.Text` ?

Comment: @DaniilIaitskov You're thinking of [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce)? [`cast`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.0.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#v:cast) will only succeed for things that are exactly `Text` (not newtype wrappers).